# Preview full XML from ScrollView without the telephone frame in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am wondering how can i preview my XML, without the telephone frame and see all the activity/fragment. 
Why i want to do that? Because i'm using lots of ScrollViews and sometimes is impossible to see what's after the bottom of the telephone.

Is there any way to accomplish that?

[image: screen frame doesn't fit example]

Comment: for android studio 2.2 and above follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460227/android-studio-designer-preview-how-to-include-device-frame/43132508#43132508

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, You can set scrollview on top layout of xml and click on design tab.
Now see the first button of the above toolbar, press it and u can see full view of all layouts in xml.

For Example see below image:

[image]

Comment: At first, i coudn't find any option for that. But then, i realized the scrollView must be the main layout of the file, and i had it inside a Relative Layout. thank you

Comment: @MarcoBarbosa for android studio 2.2 and above follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460227/android-studio-designer-preview-how-to-include-device-frame/43132508#43132508

Answer (score 0):

In the toolbar above the preview pane, click on the settings icon (cogwheel) and deselect "Include Device Frame (if available)"

Comment: thank's for the answer, but i still can't see all the activity/fragment area.