# Android Studio include device frames missing

Tags: android, android-studio, preview

I just installed Android Studio 2.2.3 for mac.
I want to change device preview but I cannot find where is the settings for that.

Older version there was layout - settings-> include device frame

Comment: Possible duplicate of this already answered question:
[android studio designer preview: how to include device frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460227/android-studio-designer-preview-how-to-include-device-frame/43725306#43725306)

Answer (score 0):

Oh... I just searched and found that if you activate the designer (click anywhere on the phone screen) then press "F" in the keyboard, the frame will come out. Press "F" again to remove it.