# Android Preview add new Device Frame

Tags: android, frame, device, preview

I want to check from the Preview Explorer how my layout looks on a 8.0 inch tablet but in Android Studio (3.1) there is no such tablet in the device list.

[image]

From Add Device Definition you just open the list of virtual devices and that's it....

I already seen the post about how to include other frame:
[android studio designer preview: how to include device frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460227/android-studio-designer-preview-how-to-include-device-frame) . But that doesn't cover it for Android Studio 3.1